# Under what close vote questions with a scope too narrrow to help other readers?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Unlike many sites, we don’t have a close reason for such questions. While some will arg this isn’t ok by the design of the stack exchange network, many sites like security.se accept such questions in certain circumstances *(in the case of security typicall a particular ᴄᴠᴇ)*.

so for such questions are until we decided on meta *(here)* that they aren’t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Narrow questions should not be closed just because they are narrow; on the contrary, narrow questions are *exactly* what all our guidance on asking questions is focused on achieving.

Narrow questions are generally characterised by a well-defined and well-specified product request, which is what we want to see. Instead, these questions should be upvoted.